# Change full : App displayName, logo, iOS and Android [2018]?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I have an existing app, on both stores, iOS, and Android. But I want to change the logo and of course the Name.

- I saw that I couldn't change the bundle ID (for ex: `mobile.myapp.com`) because it will create an entirely new app without savings ratings and downloads number.
- So I wanted to know that, if I was only modifying the display Name, there was a chance for the user to still access the bundle ID and see the previous name? And if it will affect the referencing on the store?
- For iOS, I can modify: `Bundle Display Name`without modify bundle ID right?

In both case, generally how long is the time review for submitting a completely new app or just an update but with modifications on the name and logo?

Thanks for the help